# Will electromagnetism separate into electricity and magnetism as the universe cools down?

Tags: electromagnetism, symmetry-breaking

The electroweak force separated into the weak force and electromagnetism. So, will the electromagnetic force eventually separate into electricity and magnetism?

Comment: @Frobenius I think the OP is asking about the gauge symmetry-breaking that has occurred as the universe has cooled.

Comment: @G. Smith : You are absolutely right. I didn't  realize this important detail till I saw the 2 answers.

Comment: No. Without electricity there is no electromagnetism.

Comment: Has no lab stuck some electric and magnetic items in a great big test chamber and pumped out all the heat?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In the case of electroweak force and electromagnetism there is an Higgs mechanism, which makes the $W^{\pm}, Z$ bosons massive, and preserves the photon $\gamma$ massless. But the symmetry relating the electric and magnetic fields is actually a Lorentz symmetry, which is global and remains unbroken. The difference between electric and magnetic fields emerges in non-relativistic limit, but it is not tied with the breaking of symmetry.

Comment: Could you explain how this is related to the cooling of the universe?

Comment: @nick012000 It's not. The point is that it doesn't matter how hot or cold the universe is, the way in which electric and magnetic are related makes them inseparable.

Comment: @nick012000 concering the separation into electric and magnetic field, there is no relation, there is a unified electromagnetic force, concerning the electroweak force, when the universe was hot enough - there was an unbroken $SU(2)$ group, when Universe cooled enough - phase transition occured

Answer (score 16):

No. Separating electric fields from magnetic fields would require the breaking of local Lorentz symmetry, not some gauge symmetry, and there is no reason why that is going to happen.

Comment: Can you explain how this would be related to the cooling of the universe?

Comment: @nick012000 In the Standard Model of particle physics, the weak nuclear force and the EM force are unified at high temperature because the Higgs field has a zero value. At low temperature they are separate forces because the Higgs field settles into the bottom if its “Mexican hat” potential where it has a nonzero value.

Answer (score -6):

Yes.

When the universe becomes big enough and thin enough there will be nothing but the most basic sub sub sub  particles and no forces.

Comment: Citation?‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎ -------------